# Cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float32 object

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am building a line detection program. When I run the following code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/line-detection-python-opencv-houghline-method/,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('spot.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

# This returns an array of r and theta values
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180, 200)

# The below for loop runs till r and theta values are in the range of the 2d array
for r_theta in lines[0]:
    r, theta = r_theta[0]

    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)

    x0 = a*r
    y0 = b*r
    
    # x1 stores the rounded off value of (rcos(theta)-1000sin(theta))
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    
    # y1 stores the rounded off value of (rsin(theta)+1000cos(theta))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))

    # x2 stores the rounded off value of (rcos(theta)+1000sin(theta))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    
    # y2 stores the rounded off value of (rsin(theta)-1000cos(theta))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
    
    # draw line from (x1,y1) to (x2, y2)
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,0,255),2)
    

cv2.imwrite('Lines', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 16>()
     15 # The below for loop runs till r and theta values are in the range of the 2d array
     16 for r_theta in lines[0]:
---> 17     r, theta = r_theta[0]
     19     a = np.cos(theta)
     20     b = np.sin(theta)

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float32 object
```

What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: You need to inspect what `r_theta` contains.

Comment: please send your feedback to feedback@geeksforgeeks.org

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you should use `r, theta = r_theta` without `[0]` or get every value separatelly `r = r_theta[0]` `theta = r_theta[1]`

Comment: Is your `lines` correct?  `for r_theta in lines[0]:  r, theta = r_theta[0]` should work if `lines` is a (m,n,p,2) array or equivalent list.  That is `lines[0]` selects the first element, the `for` iterates on that, `r_theta[[0]` selects an element from that, and `r,theta` splits that into 2 numbers.

Comment: Look at the comments of your link.  They say it doesn't work.  Don't try to use third party code that you don't understand, and does not provide support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

If you read comments in [your link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/line-detection-python-opencv-houghline-method/) then you see that this code is for older version

```
Devarshi (5 months ago)

The above code was copied directly from OpenCV docs 
and doesn't run on the current versions anymore. 
Incase someone is stuck. HoughLinesP mehod could be helpful. 

Try this,
```

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('path/to/image.png')
gray  = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)

minLineLength = 5
maxLineGap = 10

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
    edges,           # Input edge image
    1,               # Distance resolution in pixels
    np.pi/180,       # Angle resolution in radians
    threshold=100,   # Min number of votes for valid line
    minLineLength=5, # Min allowed length of line
    maxLineGap=10    # Max allowed gap between line for joining them
)

for points in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = points[0]
    cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    lines_list.append([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)])

cv2.imwrite('detectedLines.png',image)
```

Link [HoughLinesP](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga8618180a5948286384e3b7ca02f6feeb)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

If you would use `print(r_theta)` to see what you have in variable then you would know:

You should run without `[0]`

```
r, theta = r_theta
```

Or you should get every value separatelly

```
r     = r_theta[0] 
theta = r_theta[1]
```

---

But I think you should remove `[0]` from `lines`

```
for r_theta in lines:      # <-- without `[0]`
    r, theta = r_theta[0]  # <-- with `[0]`
```

and this should use all values `r, theta` from `lines`.

Comment: Assuming this is working code from some other source, the problem isn't with all the `[0]`, but with the dimensions of `lines` to start with.  I deduce that `lines` needs to be a 4d array, or equivalent nested lists.  The unpacking assumes the last dimension is 2; but otherwise it is taking the first [0] of all dimensions.

Comment: @hpaulj original code in link gives the same error - I think this code has bug at the beginning.

Comment: OK, I looked at the comments on the linked page, which point to the same problem.

Comment: @hpaulj you are right - now I also checked comments and see in first comment `"The above code was copied directly from OpenCV docs and doesn't run on the current versions anymore"` :) It explains all. I will add this to answer.